# Passing Value Between Two Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mdi

I have two project and having trouble on passing value between two project. As usual I have passed the file reference between project.

### My project Details Is:

```
Project1                Project2
All forms and object    Only 1 MDI Forms Containing ManuStrip
```

I wants to read the data of MDI Forms on showing the project1 forms
The Example  is as below:

```
//This is on Project2 MDI Forms

    private void accountMasterToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        INVOICE1.Form24 f24 = new INVOICE1.Form24();
        f24.PFrom.Text = label4.Text;
        f24.PTo.Text = label5.Text;
        f24.Namee.Text = textBox1.Text;
        f24.ID.Text = label6.Text;
        f24.ShowDialog();



    }
```

I Have Created the Properties for the same on project1 forms

```
   public Label PFrom
    {
        get { return label14; }
        set { label14 = value; }

    }
    public Label PTo
    {
        get { return label16; }
        set { label16 = value; }

    }
    public Label Namee
    {
        get { return label2; }
        set { label2 = value; }

    }
    public Label ID
    {
        get { return label3; }
        set { label3 = value; }

    }
```

The value passed from MDI To Project1 is not showing on Form24 of Project1. There are no error. The Form24 Showing without value which are passed from MDI Form.

Why The value not showing on form24 of project1 ?. And What is the Solution?.

Comment: You haven't provided an actual problem here, other than "It's not working." Please provide an error, an exception, a warning, or some other real symptom of your problem.

Comment: Please show the Form24 constructor, Load, and Shown methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have forgotten to add a project reference to Project1 in Project2. In the Solution Explorer, right-click Project2 and select "Add Reference", then under "Projects" select Project1.

Also, if the two projects have different namespaces, you'll need to put

```
using Project1;  // replace "Project1" with the namespace of your Project1
```

At the top of the Project2 source file.

---

If there are no compiler errors then the problem is not likely to be with project references. Perhaps you have some code in the Form24 constructor or Load event which is clearing those labels

---

As a side note, instead of exposing the Labels as properties, just expose their Text property:

```
public string PFrom       
{           
    get { return label14.Text; }           
    set { label14.Text = value; }          
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have passed the file reference in the project

Comment: .... Suppose If I have a Single Project and I have just pass the file reference on it then what to do?.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand "passed the file reference". I also don't understand the question you just asked. Try to provide more details about the problem - what is/isn't happening? Are there any compile or runtime errors?

Comment: There are not any compiler or runtime errors, I just want to ask that if there are only single project and if I have passed a .exe file reference of other project on the same project then how to get it work?. I mean how to passed the value from same project to reference file project?.

Comment: If there are no compiler errors then the problem is not likely to be with project references. Perhaps you have some code in the Form24 constructor or Load event which is clearing those labels.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable guidance, I was really struggling for a while before your suggestion and the matters is solved with your kind guidance.

Comment: ... Actually I have passed Global Variable like singleTon on Form24_Load event for the above label and the matters solved after disabled/removed the same. Thank you very much

Comment: @IgbyLargeman 6 years later and this helped me with a big issue on my side. Thank you

Comment: @vipersassassin Awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same problem..and answer was simple: it is impossible. However you can crack this situation...using database or shared solution in which you will establish communication between 2 projects. Or use 3 project and create communication driver, which will be used in 1 and 2 project. It does't meter how you will do this.

1. situation: database
2. situation: shared solution with communication protocol
3. perhaps creating DLL will also help

My personal solution was this: (Tested on real website and separate background project)

To create shared project, use VS template (shared project). Then create your class and inside each project include in project reference section your shared project. So for example Project A, Project B , Project SharedPr -> contains communication protocol

Project A -> references-> Add Reference -> Shared Project.

Project B -> references-> Add Reference -> Shared Project.

That communication protocol it is something like a driver which you need to create.

Easily to do this by FILE. Create Hidden file in which project A writes and project B reads. Store in your file json string or json array then read all lines and deserialize everything for example with Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package.

I hope this will help.